# Wordpress git workflow, how to decline a repo to create new sites for clients?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm new to the the git workflow process and I'm working as a web designer / web developper and creating many sites for many clients. I forked a Wordpress repository to create my own base with all my favorites plugins & configurations.

I just would like to know what do I need to do, after I have forked and customize a basic install to create my others others sites, based on this starter config that I have made?

To create a new client site, do I need to fork it again, into another repository, or do I just need to clone it into another folder ?

I'm just wondering that, if I only clone it, and then make some changes, it will update the forked base theme (that I don't want to do). I want to keep the base dev repo clean.
But, I also want, after creating some new sites from my main repository (the forked one / the developpement based wordpress configuration), to be able to make some change, for example as new release on this main repository, and then import them into my sub-sites, created from that main repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git clone "path to wordpress repo on my hardrive" "path to a brand new folder"
```

nothing will happen to the original repo unless you tell git to do so.

to import some changes from original to a "fork":

```
git pull
```

in the fork.

That's the power of **git**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what i mean is that i forked the wordpress-skeleton git theme to create my own base developpment tool, to quickly create new sites for my clients. I have created the git flow (master & develop branches) to configure and customize it. Now, imagine that from it, i wan't to create two differents new sites for my clients. Do i need to create a new branche for each site ? Or a 2 forks from starter configuration ? or 2 clones ?

Comment: dont create branches , clone your master repo into other folders,that's exactly what i wrote you.Clients dont share the same project do they? so just put each client in a different clone repo and when you want them to be in sync with the master just `git pull`

Comment: ah okay! thanks a lot. i was thinking that only cloning would not allow me to sync some changes with the master repo. Thanks again!

Comment: Well .. euuh .. i'm still missing something :/ If i clone it, i only get a local copy on my computer, but i don't get a repository created on my bitbucket account, so i can't select it on ftploy. So, how i would i tell to ftploy that i have a single project, different from the base install & project, to deploy to an ftp server ?
Maybe should it be better to fork it instead of cloning it so ?

Comment: AAAAh! Got it! Forking is only need if i do not have write permission on the repo, right ? So i created the repo for my client site on my bitbucket, and then pushed my local repo to the corresponding bitbucket repo. Wow thats awesome! Sorry for that. Was just a bit confused about the process :)